# Is it possible to create a GUI that doesn't run in an external window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, console

I want to create a GUI in python, but I don't want it to open in a window. But is it possible? A GUI that runs just like a `print("hello world")` program would run and doesn't open in a new window of its own? When you run the hello world program it prints hello world in the console. Is anything at least **close** to that possible for a GUI? If it is possible, how would I go about implementing it in python?

Comment: Suppose you were to start your Hello World program by double-clicking on its name in Explorer. Where would you expect the output to appear, if not in a new window? Recall that the Windows console is *also* a window. As @Prune says, what you want may be possible, but that would entail rewriting `cmd.exe` which is a project a that is more ambitious than you seem to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the few things that's not possible -- at least, not *practical*.  The output window of your Python interpreter is preconfigured by the run-time system with its characteristics; those include being the recipient of the data channel `stdout` and `stderr`.  These channels have character-oriented data handlers, such that the bytes coming down that line are taken as a simple character stream, rather than RGB values, or positioning commands.

Depending on your interpreter's implementation, it *might* be possible to reach back into the run-time definitions and reconfigure the streams to your will, but you'd have a lot of work to do, to handle both the graphics you want *and* the expected characteristics of those streams.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is possible! But how would I implement it? What do I do? What code to write? What algorithm to follow? Kindly ellaborate.

Comment: That request is *far* too broad for Stack Overflow -- and, as I've said, it depends on your interpreter.

Comment: my interpreter is python3.9 and I'm using visual studio code on win10/debian(dual boot). Is it possible with these circumstances?

Comment: I have no idea -- that research is *your* task.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  Giving you a personal tutorial on those techniques is out of scope.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're asking to do is to entirely replace a standard part of your interpreter.  This is *not* a task for someone lacking insight, excellent skills, and courage.  :-)  This is subverting the run-time system, not something as straightforward as setting up a file writer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can do GUI without window...
But the main purpose of GUI is that you have something window-like-that-you-can-interact-with...

Also you can start GUI with terminal, but still opens in a its own window.
But if you wanna implement GUI in python check Kivy and Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a gui without the console
its simple
first you need to convert it to exe for that

1. pip install pyinstaller
2. run cmd
3. type   **pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole 'path'** where path is like d:/something/file.py

#i would recommend eel library for nearly no framework gui development as initial phase.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted the exact *opposite* of that. My doubt has been cleared by @Prune. Thanks, though.